# Attaining an Integer from StorageKey

Tags: subxt

I'm porting a script from TypeScript using the Polkadot.JS/api to Rust using Subxt.

```
    let query = polkadot::storage().referenda().referendum_info_for_root();

    let mut results = api.storage().at_latest().await?.iter(query,10).await?;

    while let Some((key, value)) = results.next().await? {
```

With reference to the above, I'm having trouble getting the `referendum id` from the `key`.  Within my TypeScript code I would use something like `key.toHuman()[0]`.

Regards,

Comment: What kind of trouble did you encounter?

Comment: You dont have to use toHuman() here, have you tried to print the key and the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from @Turboflakes the developer behind CrunchBot.  He referred me to an article and supported with some code to help 'decode' the Storage key.

https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/transparent-keys-in-substrate/

Within the while loop I use:

`get_ref_id_from_storage_key(key.0.to_vec())`

The function's details are:

```
pub fn get_ref_id_from_storage_key(key: Vec<u8>) -> u32 {
    let s = &key[key.len() - 4..];
    let v: [u8; 4] = s.try_into().expect("slice with incorrect length");
    u32::from_le_bytes(v)
}
```